# react native custom horizontal list with centered item

Tags: react-native, scrollview, carousel, flatlist

I want to build this component or something similar in react-native using FlatList or Scrollview.
there is any plugin or custom code?
i tries react-native-snap-carousel but does'nt works with me.

i tried to coding it many times, but does'nt work.

[custom horizontal list image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7bTa9.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.